Shipping Methods not displaying after user creates an account in checkout 2.3.4
We are having an issue on our storefronts if user doesn't have an account and they create an account during checkout that the shipping rates will not show.
But if user logs out and logs in manually shipping rates will show.
Landing checkout page is the same in both instances, but refresh seems to be needed after creating an account.  Any way to do this without additional step for user?
Page example: https://url.com/unique_Storeview/checkout/#shipping
